# How to solve the constrained linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

$W \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times 1}$, $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $n<p$.

Here is the problem: $Wa = b$ with constraint $WW^T = K$ where K, a, b are given.

Since $n<p$, we have K full rank. How to analysis the existence of W or even compute the W? Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Should $b$ be in $\Bbb R^{n \times 1}$ then?

Comment: By considering a Cholesky decomposition $K = LL^T$, you can reduce this to the case where $WW^T = I_{n \times n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $K^{-1} = LL^T$ is a Cholesky decomposition where $L$ is $n \times p$.  Then we can rewrite
$$
Wa = b, \quad WW^T = K \implies\\
Wa = b, \quad (LW)(LW)^T = I \implies\\
(LW)a = (Lb), \quad (LW)(LW)^T = I.
$$
That is, if we make the substitution $M = LW$ and $y = LB$, then your problem is equivalent to solving
$$
Ma = y, \qquad MM^T = I.
$$
Notably, the constraint that $MM^T = I$ simply means that the rows of $M$ are orthonormal.  One approach to construct such an $M$ is as follows:

- Find any matrix satisfying $PP^T = I$ for which $\|Pa\| = \|y\|$
- Find an orthogonal matrix $U$ satisfying $U(Pa) = y$
- Take $M = UP$

Notably, the reframed problem will have a solution if and only if $\|y\| \leq \|a\|$.